# Excel Add up columns regardless of row

Tags: excel

I have data like this in an excel sheet:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

What I am trying to do is come up with a formal that will give me the total of each row, something like this `=A+B+C`, so I can use this formula on each row...I have plenty of rows, The above is just and example, I have this `=A1+B1+C1` is there away in excel to get A1 + B1 + C1  without the row number?

Please help, this would save me lots of time.

I have looked into =ROW to get the row number, can I use the sum function with the row function?

`=SUM(A=ROW():B=ROW())`

I found a solution to my problem:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()):INDIRECT("C"&ROW()))`

Comment: Why can't you just auto-extend `=A1+B1+C1`?  that's the usual practice.

Comment: Whay don't you want the row number? If you select the cell with the formula, click on the small square on the corner and drag it to the bottom, each row will have its own formula... `=A1+B1+C1`, `=A2+B2+C2`, and so on. By the way, you can also simplify it: `=SUM(A1:C1)`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()):INDIRECT("C"&ROW()))
```

Comment: Massively over complicated for what you need. Good use of `INDIRECT` though